# Losing network connections when using GPS

Tags: gps, connection-issues, mobile-network, htc-one-s

I'm having the same kind of problem as described in these threads, using a rooted HTC One S with Dark Jelly S rom:

[Thread on XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1708799)
[Thead on CyanogenMod Forum](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/5443-resolved-google-maps-gps-disconnect-the-data-connection/)

When activating GPS while using either WiFi or 3G, after a couple of seconds I'm losing GPS fix and mobile data connection. WiFi stays active. 
I also get a notifaction "Restricted access changed".

I only have 1 APN in my settings, this happens on both the CM10 rom and Dark Jelly S rom.

Further information:

```
VLE PVT SHIP S-ON RL
HBOOT-1.09.0000
RADIO-0.16.314018.17_2
OpenDSP-v25.1.0.32.0405
eMMC-boot
Apr 2 2012,21:08:24
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you try updating your phone software and/or clearing your cache?

Comment: I've tried several full-wipes, after which the problem seems to be gone, but after a while it reoccures again.

Comment: How about software updates?

Comment: What updates do you mean with that?

Comment: What I meant was **system updates**. NOT *software*. Sorry about that.

Comment: Well, I do have the latest version of the ROM, I've also tried the three radio's that applied to my location (the EU versions).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6773/discussion-between-sid-and-niek)