# HTC Sensation XE, Mobile data OFF when GPS ON

Tags: gps, mobile-data, htc-sensation-xe

When any app on my android device started to read GPS (with GPS icon ON at notification area), my mobile data connection is OFF right away and then ON again after about 10-20 seconds. It happens in every app and that's really annoys me.

I've tried to uncheck the "Google's Location Service" at "Location" settings menu, but it affects nothing.

Anyone has same problem with me? What's the solutions?

Comment: Related: [Losing network connections when using GPS](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35490/16575). No answers yet, though – but maybe it gives you some clue. Interesting parallel: It's also a HTC device there (One S), so there might be a "common cause".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution !!! It's an old bug that some people are trailing since Android 1.6, and wich is always not actualy corrected !

The solution : you must have only one APN set in your mobile network configuration.

Comment: Thanks again @Izzy, I found the solution here [source](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/5443-resolved-google-maps-gps-disconnect-the-data-connection/)

Comment: So it must be something device (or manufacturer) specific, as I'm not affected (ir simply didn't notice?) on any device so far. Thanks for sharing the solution!